# Flutter : black screen using stream controller

Tags: flutter, mvvm, streamcontroller

I am creating e-commerce app using MVVM architecture where I am using Stream Controller in ViewModel Class. When I change the orientation of my phone screen it says

**Bad state: Stream has already been listened to**

I have tried the adding the .broadcast When I initialize the stream controller

```
final StreamController _streamController = StreamController<ViewObject>.broadcast();
```

But still the output is not as desired instead the screen becomes blank.

Answer (score -1):

**To fix this issue, you can cancel the stream subscription when the ViewModel class is disposed. You can do this by overriding the dispose method in your ViewModel class and calling the cancel method on the stream subscription. Here is an example**

```
class MyViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final StreamController _streamController = StreamController<ViewObject>.broadcast();
  Stream<ViewObject> get myStream => _streamController.stream;

  MyViewModel() {
    // Add data to the stream controller
    _streamController.add(myData);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Issue resolved. What I did is, I disposed the view model class and initialized it again in the build function before StreamBuilder renders. This way every time build function is called the previous controller is closed and new one starts to listen.